# Post not found when filtered by category ID

Tags: categories, query-posts

On my home page I am trying to filter by a category type and limit it to one post; but I keep getting "no posts found". Here is my following code:

```
<?php query_posts('cat=34&showposts=1'); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `post_per_page` instead.  Like this:

```
query_posts( 'cat=34&posts_per_page=5' );
```

Read more about the query on: [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)